# Slide Show using ViewPager and Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, timer, android-viewpager

I have created a very simple slide show using viewpager. To auto slide I have used a timer for every 5 seconds. I have a X button to close the slide show in the middle of the slide. When I press the X the app closes the slideshow goes to MainActivity. All this is working fine but when I open the slideshow activity 
again from MainActivity the first image comes up properly but then the next one jumps to last image from the array, doesn't show other images. Could be timer issue or something else. I am purging and cancelling the timer

Please check my code below:

I have set the images in Array and adding them to arrayList.

```
private static final Integer[] LANDSCAPEIMAGES = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8, R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,
        R.drawable.image11};

private ArrayList<Integer> imagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Timer swipeTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slideshow);

    swipeTimer = new Timer();

    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //init();
    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //init();
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        initLand();
    }

    mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

  private void initLand()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < LANDSCAPEIMAGES.length; i++)
        imagesArray.add(LANDSCAPEIMAGES[i]);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(StartSlideShow.this, imagesArray, this));
    NUM_PAGES = LANDSCAPEIMAGES.length;


    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //Comment for no loop.
            /*if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }*/

            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };

    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 5000, 5000);
}

//TO FINISH THE ACTIVITY AND STOP TIMER()
@Override
    public void pagerItemSelected()
    {
        Log.e("Value", "=It is coming here");

        finish();
       onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Log.e("Value", "=onBackPressed");

        swipeTimer.purge();
        swipeTimer.cancel();


    }
```

My PagerAdapter:

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    OnPagerItemSelected mListener;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES, OnPagerItemSelected listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        mListener = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position)
    {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

        ImageView quit = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.closeimage);
        quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent readMore = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(readMore);
              // ((Activity) context).finish();

                mListener.pagerItemSelected();

            }
        });

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        Log.e("Value"," - " + position);

        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);


        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }


    public interface OnPagerItemSelected {
        void pagerItemSelected();
    }

}
```

Comment: replace your slider with this https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

Comment: i think you should first cancel tasks in timer then purge it.

Comment: @Farid: Tried it. Didn't work.